# Renewing public dynamic IP via Powershell ?- Azure Resource Manager

Tags: networking, powershell, azure

i need your help! I'm trying to renew a dynamic IP assigned to a VM, but i want to figure it out if there's some possibility to accomplish this via powershell cmdlets without being in the need of shutting down and starting the VM again. I want to renew the public ip's assigned, regularly, but in a more efficient way.

Comment: Are you talking about the VIP or DIP?

Comment: there's no valid reason for doing this in a business setting

Comment: Im talking about the VIP. Actually i'm using Stop-AzureRmVM and Start-AzureRmVM to get a new IP from the pool, but i'm not convinced with this solution, it's not practical. In the classic panel, you could use Set-AzurePublicIP to asign an instance level public IP. But this cmdlet isn't working in the new panel.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? it might give us a better idea of how to help

Comment: Well, actually i'm planning to mount something similar to a traffic exchange, using azure VPS available with the free trial, to send traffic to some websites. So i need to get new ip's constantly from the pool.

Comment: Solved it with hola.org extension for browser

Answer (score 0):

```
ipconfig /release 
ipconfig /renew
```

You could use the above two commands to release and renew the given dynamic IP address. For further information open a windows-shell and type `ipconfig --help` 
In the past they where commandline commands, but you can use them in powershell as well. If you want to renew the IP regularly you need to write a cronjob which execudes the two commands in the given intervals.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But im asking how to renew the public ip associated to the VM, without having to type in powershell
Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName Grupo1 -Name VM1 -Force
Start-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName Grupo1 -Name VM1